# What is the difference between ceph rbd and iscsi in the context of Cinder volume (of type ceph)?

Tags: docker-swarm, docker-volume, ceph, iscsi, openstack-cinder

I am trying to get a [volume driver](https://github.com/akailash/cinder-docker-driver) to work on a docker swarm which uses nova instances and cinder volume and makes persistent storage available for the swarm services. 
I can only create cinder volumes of type ceph. I am modifying the driver and trying to get it to work for me, but I cannot get the TargetPortal, TargetIQN etc to do the [iscsi attach](https://github.com/akailash/cinder-docker-driver/blob/master/driver.go#L360). Should I be using RBD instead of iscsi since the volume type is ceph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using the [Rexray](https://github.com/codedellemc/rexray).
iscsi is not supported for cinder in my case. That is why these details are not returned by openstack endpoint during attach for the cinder-docker-driver.